# google cloud messaging in android lower than 4.1

Tags: android, request, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using push notifications (GCM) in my application and it works correctly when run on android 4.2.2 (Galaxy Nexus and HTC One)

Also I have a tablet (asus transformer T101 running android 4.03) and Nexus One (running Android 2.3.6)

Running the application on the tablet and the Nexus one, methods of push notifications do not work.

As indicated in the documentation, I have included android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS the permission for versions below 4.0.3, but without success.

The method that calls the library of GCM runs:

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(Hello.this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(Hola.this, "MY_ID_SENDER"); //Sender ID           
        } else {
            Log.i("masterhv", "already registered");
        }
```

But the method that handles the response is not executed (onRegistered) ... I understand that there is no response from Google

As I said, it works perfectly on devices with android 4.2.2 and 4.1, permissions are correct, but does not work on android 4.0.3 and lower.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Can you Log the message in `onError()` and see what error is returned?

Comment: Note that `GCMRegistrar` is the deprecated approach, in favor of the new `GoogleCloudMessaging`. I just happened to be working on this today, and my new book sample (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2) works on my Nexus One running 2.3.6.

Comment: @CommonsWare i´m trying to unregister but without success, any link or help? Thanks again

Comment: I have not tried unregistering, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, thanks. i´m trying:  public static void unregister(Context context) {
        Intent regIntent = new Intent(REQUEST_UNREGISTRATION_INTENT);
        regIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, new Intent(), 0));
        context.startService(regIntent);
    } ... and it´s not working :(

Answer (score 1):

With the old version of GCM (deprecated 1-2 month ago aprox.) you had to ask to the user to add a google account if he was running a version lower than 4.0.4

Looking at the API docs it is still a requirement

> Mobile Device The device that is running an Android application that uses GCM. This must be a 2.2 Android device that has Google Play Store installed, and it must have at least one logged in Google account if the device is running a version lower than Android 4.0.4. Alternatively, for testing you can use an emulator running Android 2.2 with Google APIs.

[GCM API](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

I have not used the last version. If you decide to use the old one you have to generate an  acces to the account settings to add an account:

```
private String[] getAccountNames() {        
        AccountManager accMan = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accArray = accMan.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        String[] names = new String[accArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            names[i] = accArray[i].name;
        }
    return names;
}
```

So if the array is 0 you can pop-up a dialog asking to move to the account settings.

Without an account if you try to register you should see on your logcat a message error ACCOUNT_MISSING.