# Android Google Cloud Messaging Error Not Registered

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application with push notifications. It works fine on my phone (OS Android 4.2.2) but when trying to send a message to the tablet (Android 3.2) an error is given: "NotRegistered". Actually the tablet is registered and when I call register() the result is that the device is already registered and gives me the regId. I have all the permissions in the manifest. What could be the problem?

**Edit:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

this line wasn't in the manifest when  I registered the device. I added it, used unregister(), then I called register() again and the problem still occurs. Also after unregister() and regiter() the id is the same.

Comment: Are You have filled google account on tablet?

Comment: Yes, I even have two logged in google accounts. I can download apps from google play.

Answer (score 0):

[google cloud messaging in android lower than 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708128/google-cloud-messaging-in-android-lower-than-4-1)

A Google account is a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or lower.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: I have a google account. The permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> wasn't added. I added it to the manifest, used unregister() and after that register() again. The id is the same, the problem is still here..